# Determine feedback capacitor values for transimpedance amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, feedback, transimpedance

I need to decide feedback capacitance Cf for the for transimpedance amplifier. I have the confusion. Which equation is appropriate for finding the Cf?

Cf= 1/(2*pi*Rf*fp), where fp is the frequency enter to the Op amp? In our case it would be around GHz range.

or

this one Cf= √(Cin/(2*pi*Rf*fp)), where the input capacitance is also needed for the calculation?

or

this one Cf= √(Cin/(2*pi*Rf*GBW)), where GBW is the gain bandwidth product of the op amp (8 GHz). In this case, it seems input frequency is not needed to calculate the Cf.

I know how to decide Rf.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, a schematic diagram showing what circuit you are specifically talking about would help : )

Comment: These equations adress different requirements. It has to be there to compensate for the input capacitance, when the Rf and GBW meet certain conditions. In addition, you can spec it higher to form a deliberate lowpass.